# Google Maps : Working with mixed type coordinate formats

Tags: javascript, google-maps

**Problem Statement** : I have Database entries of co-ordinates in different formats as follows.

> Degrees and decimal minutes (DMM): 41 24.2028, 2 10.4418
>
> Decimal  degrees (DD): 41.40338, 2.17403

**My Question** : Will Google Maps API automatically detect the type and place a marker ? Or a format conversion is required before feeding the data to the API ?

**If not -> My Approach to the Solution** : Default, I will be using the DD format.
DMM format will be detected as

```
if (latitude.indexOf(' ') > 0) {
    convert(latitude) 
}
```

Am I going in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Google Maps API won't magically detect coordinates projection or format, because it waits for [EPSG:3857](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857) formatted coordinates.

So you'll have to process the coordinates before sending them to Google Maps API and make sure they match the WebMercator (see link I provided) expectations. Your example is going in this direction, which is good I think.